# How to write Unit Test case for Zend Db Table Row

Tags: phpunit, zend-db, zend-db-table

I am trying to write test case for my Row classes and I don't really what is the proper way to  do that.

I've seen many example use model & table, for example http://techportal.inviqa.com/2010/12/07/unit-testing-databases-with-zend-framework/.

The case doesn't use Row at all and the model is all about getters and setters. I don't want rewrite such things as the Zend_Db_Table_Row can do it automatically.

My row classes are extended from Zend_Db_Table_Row, I don't think there is necessary to write test cases like getters & setters.

And most my row classes are like following

```
class App_Table_Row_User extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract {

}
```

Then, in order to get a better test case coverage, what kind of test case I should write for  a class like above?

Answer (score 3):

I presume you need to populate object's attributes (table's column name => values) and run tests for your custom methods.

Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract constructor has one parameter - associative array with following keys:

- table
- data
- stored
- readOnly

To build useful for testing object you should use at least the "data" entries. It is associative array too. The "data" array has column names as keys and row data as values. So the testing object setUp may look as follows:

```
   $this->object = new App_Table_Row_User(     
     array(
       'data' => array(  
         'username' => 'Jon Doe',  
         'password' => 'qwerty',  
         'email' => 'j.doe@example.com'  
       )
     ) 
   );
```

You can pass `NULL` as values in the "data" array entries if you need something similar to the `fetchNew` return object.
If you are using "save" or any method that requires the table model, I will suggest using mock/stub object and passing it as the "table" parameter in the constructor. You can control any Db related operation that way.

Hope that helps :)